# Python giving 'module' object is not callable when trying to create instance with class reference variable

Tags: python, jython

I'm getting an error "module object is not callable" when trying to create a class with a reference: import LoginPage as loginPage. 
However, when I try to import just the class itself import LoginPage.LoginPage as loginPage I get a different error saying the module does not contain that object.

Im not sure if its the way I am creating the object through the reference with parenthesis. Is there another way to do this? I also had tried pageClassRef.LoginPage(), same error 'module' is not callable

```
import ....
import inspect
import LoginPage as loginPage

#Singleton class type
class Singleton(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dic)
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance

class NavTestSession(object):

    # Config properties
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, configManager):
        self.cfgManager = configManager


        self.navTestEngine = NavTestEngine.Navigator(navVersion, resolution, scoreList)


    def getConfigManager(self):
        return self.cfgManager

    def startNavigating(self):
        return self.createPageObject(loginPage)


def createPageObject(self, pageClassRef):
    # Create page factory method and validation

    newPageObj = pageClassRef()
    #print(newPageObj)
    newPageObj.validatePage()

    return newPageObj

def startNewSession(self):
    loginPage = self.navTestEngine.launchAppFromMenu()

    return loginPage
```

LoginPage.py

```
import NavPageObject

class LoginPage(NavPageObject):

    # Image to validate the current page
    PAGE_VALIDATION_IMAGE = "Views_SIGNIN.png"

    # Images of objects on the current page

    USERNAME_INPUT_FIELD_1 = "Input_USERNAME_1.png"

    USERNAME_INPUT_FIELD_2 = "Input_USERNAME_2.png"

    PASSWORD_INPUT_FIELD = "Input_PASSWORD.png"

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginPage, self).__init__()

    def validatePage(self):
        if not self.navTestEngine.imageExists(self.PAGE_VALIDATION_IMAGE, 
super().getCurrentRegion()):
            raise FindFailed("Page Validation fail at %s" % __file__)

    def typeUsername(self, username):
        self.navTestEngine.clickWithRetry(USERNAME_INPUT_FIELD_1)

        type("blahblah")

        return self

    def typePassword(self, password):
        return self

    def clickLogin(self):
        return self
```

Comment: `import LoginPage as loginPage` makes the *module itself* accessible under the name `loginPage`.  The class contained in that module would then be accessible as `loginPage.loginPage`.  Or, you could use `from LoginPage import loginPage`.

Comment: still no luck, the thing is no matter how I try to access or assign LoginPage.LoginPage it still see it as a module and not a class reference. I may just need to loop through the modules objects until I get what im looking for. I also tried renaming the file to something different then the class. No luck

Answer (score 1):

i think the problems is that you trying to import LoginPage as loginPage.
why don't you just type "from LoginPage import LoginPage as logingpage"

Comment: still no luck, the thing is no matter how I try to access or assign LoginPage.LoginPage it still see it as a module and not a class reference. I may just need to loop through the modules objects until I get what im looking for. I also tried renaming the file to something different then the class. No luck